# Web based Message system

Tags: database-design, messaging

I am at design stage of a simple private message inbox solution for a small MVC application.How do I **design the database** to be able to track a parent message(new message) and subsequent children(reply).Any ASP.NET tutorial to get me started would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
message
----------
message_id
message_body
author_id

message_reply
--------------
message_id
reply_id
```